# How can I get the root account to generate an acceptable ssh key?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, ssh-keys

On an ubuntu machine I did the following:

```
~$ sudo su -
[sudo] password for jamie:
root@mydomain:~# ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
12:34:56:78:9a:bc:de:f0:12:34:56:78:9a:bc:de:f0 root@mydomain.ca
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
root@mydomain:~# cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -p 443 jamie@remote.server.box 'cat > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
jamie@remote.server.box's password:
root@mydomain:~# ssh jamie@remote.server.box
jamie@remote.server.box's password:
```

It's asking me for a password.

However, using a regular account, the following works:

```
$ cd ; ssh-keygen -t rsa ; cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh jamie@remote.server.box 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
$ ssh jamie@remote.server.box
Last login: Thu Oct 24 14:48:41 2013 from 173.45.232.105
[jamie@remote.server.box ~]$
```

Which leads me to believe it's not an issue of `authorized_keys` versus `authorized_keys2` or permissions.

*Why does the 'root' account accessing the remote 'jamie' account not work?*

The remote machine is CentOS if that's relevant.

Comment: In both cases you're adding the key to the `authorized_keys` of the same user. There is no reason why it would let you log in as root. Besides that, root login might simply be disabled (as it should be). As long as you're allowed to elevate, just log in as "jamie" and use `sudo` once logged on.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I wasn't clear; I want the root account on the Ubuntu machine to have access to the 'jamie' account on the remote, not 'root'.

Comment: I bet it has something to do with the way you use `su`.  What is `$HOME` set as after you `su`?  Try it again with `su -` and maybe it will work better.

Comment: I'm not sure if this matters (it probably doesn't), but I don't think `sudo su ; cd` does what you want. The `cd` won't be processed in the elevated shell, but only after you log out of it.

Comment: Can you verify if the public key you generated as root is properly added to the `authorized_keys` on the remote side? You might also want to have a look at `ssh-copy-id`

Comment: @OliverSalzburg You're quite right about the `sudo su; cd`; I actually  entered the two commands not on one line, but only cut and pasted the `ssh-keygen` lines.

Comment: @KevinPanko Looking at the contents of the `id_rsa.pub`, the file had the credentials I expected (`root@...`); so I don't think it's that.  Regardless, `echo ${HOME}` outputs "`/root`", as does `cd ; pwd` in the su shell.

Comment: You're using `cat > authorized_keys` for root but `cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` for the other user. Is that right?

Comment: This is a poorly formulated request. In the example as root, Jamie is trying to connect to port 443, in the example as normal user to port 22. He purports to show how he generated the keys, but that's obviously different from what really happened: neither as root nor as jamie, he moved the key to the server, and inserted it into the authorized_key file. In other words, jamie gives incomplete or altogether wrong info on his MO. Of course he found the solution by himself, he is the only one who had all the facts.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae And yet, I still very much appreciate you spending the time to criticize the whole process.

Comment: Ty for being so nice, but pls let me re-state that you have to learn how to ask for help. You must strive to give us all the facts, as they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/90465/14447

probably should mark this question as duplicate of the same.

Comment: Unfortunately stack exchange does not currently support linking questions between sites.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Yes, and duplicates must be in the same site.  The question would need to be migrated first and then it could be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Try running ssh in verbose mode.  I find this often provides a clue as to what is happening.

Check the security on the directories all the way to .ssh on the target machine.  If any directories are world or group writable, this can cause ssh to refuse to access your authorized keys file.  I believe the .ssh directory must be not be accessible to either group or world.

Try creating a key file on the remote and adding the public key to the authorized_keys file.  Get `ssh localhost` working first, then try remote access.

You can configure the `.ssh/config` file on root to add the user for you.  Something like this should work:

```
host remote
    hostname remote.server.box
    user=jamie
```